# npm install is not installing grunt js from dependencies

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to automatic all the package installations automatic for developers. So I have both package.json and grunt file in the same directory. I want to do npm install first so that all dependencies will be installed and when developer executes grunt on command line things will be ready. May I know why it is not working. The other thing is may I know the difference between dependency and devdependencies.

```
{
  "name": "TestProject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "this project is for test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.7",
    "uglify-js": "~2.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-watch":"~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.2",
    "qunit": "~1.11.0"
  },  
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "qunit": "~1.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-watch":"~0.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably missing the command-line utility for Grunt.

That can be installed in your shell, using

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

The CLI is distributed independently from the `grunt` package or the `grunt-` plugins. You should include instructions to install `grunt-cli` globally in the same dev environment setup documentation where you indicate how to set up `node`, `npm`, `bower`, or the like.

## Update

If you are so adamant about installing `grunt-cli` on `npm install`, I guess one option might be using [npm scripts](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html).

Include in your `package.json` *(note: untested)*

```
{
  "postinstall": "npm i -g grunt-cli"
}
```

I'd discourage this, though. Just install them by hand.

Comment: Hi Nico, I know this part but I want to automate this. npm should look at dependency and install automatically right?

Comment: One more thing, Then what is the use of having dependency?

Comment: Dependencies in `package.json` are meant to be package-specific. Tools such as `grunt-cli` shouldn't be included in the `package.json` just as `npm`, `node`, `bower`, or `component` shouldn't. They are CLI tools, not runtime (or even development) dependencies. Your project doesn't depend on the CLI directly. You do, on a global level.

Comment: once I install grunt remaining dependencies are automatically installed by npm install. You are right node,grunt are meant for that.

Comment: See my update for a possible alternative using [npm scripts](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html), but I wouldn't encourage doing that.